# Which of abi.encodePacked and abi.encode was standard in Solidity compiler before Solidity 0.5?

Tags: solidity, bytes, keccak

Before Solidity v0.5, keccak256() took multiple arguments, and after v0.5 it requires a single bytes argument. Which of the two encoding types, encode/encodePacked, did the compiler use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was `abi.encodePacked()`. `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b, c))` on 0.5+ is equivalent to `keccak256(a, b, c)` in earlier versions.

[Solidity v0.5.0 Breaking Changes > Semantic and Syntactic Changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/050-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes)

> The functions `.call()`, `.delegatecall()`, `staticcall()`, `keccak256()`, `sha256()` and `ripemd160()` now accept only a single bytes argument. Moreover, the argument is not padded. This was changed to make more explicit and clear how the arguments are concatenated. Change every `.call()` (and family) to a `.call("")` and every `.call(signature, a, b, c)` to use `.call(abi.encodeWithSignature(signature, a, b, c))` (the last one only works for value types). Change every `keccak256(a, b, c)` to `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b, c))`.

Comment: Thank you. Very appreciated, helps a lot. I Yes I saw that text on the v0.5 update docs. But could be interpreted different ways, since keccak256(a, b, c) is not forced to be changed to abi.encodePacked, can also be changed to abi.encode, or, just any bytes sequence. I realized after your answer that I could just test myself in Remix by using compiler older than v0.5, did so, and you are correct.

Comment: Yes I agree that the wording could be more explicit but I think that in context it's still clear enough that the new version is meant to give you the same hash. The purpose of the change was just to make the lack of padding explicit and not change behavior.

Comment: I don't think it is very explicit but since it can easily just be tested, it does not matter as much. I'm not complaining, I now understand what change was made and why, and thank you a lot for your answer that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: re: the purpose, I'm pretty sure it was that there is a major security issue with encodePacked, and that prioritizing cheap hash function for large pre-images had to be abandoned. In my own contract I just use abi.encode now, since the inputs are 32-byte words and "packing" adds nothing, and since people often use 32-byte words, "packing" is only meaningful in some cases (but if one had to be chosen as standard, I would have gone with packing too if not for the security issue... )

Comment: Which vulnerability do you mean? If it's the risk of collisions with multiple dynamically-sized values then yeah, you need something like `abi.encode()` in that case and using it for everything is a safe choice too. But there are cases where `abi.encodePacked()` is completely fine (statically-sized values). `abi.encodePacked()` is just a no-op (concat values as-is with no extra work). Sometimes doing only that is not safe and you have to take extra steps but that did not change. What changed is simply that the user is now forced to explicitly choose how to concatenate them.

Comment: yeah that one but I wouldn't call it "collisions" since it is the exact same pre-image. so it actually isn't a hash collision

Comment: I'm aware packing the bytes sequence is really good when it is large because it is really GAS heavy otherwise. and I assume the reason it was changed is for the security issue. even though there are cases where "abi.encode" is standard (according to docs), like contract calls, this seems secondary in importance.

Comment: Right, "collision" was not the right word. As for why this was changed, looking at the original issue ([#3955](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3955)) the security problem is not mentioned at all. It seems to have rather been a part of a general push to get rid of functions that take multiple args and serialize them. It was done in a single PR with `call()` ([#4097](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/4097)) and padding in `call()` seems to have been a bigger concern at the time ([#3978](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3978)).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Cameel's answer I realized that I could just test myself in Remix using compiler older than v0.5. I did so, because I wanted to verify the answer, and it was correct. Since this approach is good for other noobs to use, I post it here as an answer. Solidity version has to be one that has included the `abi.encode/encodePacked` methods ([added in v0.4.24](https://medium.com/@libertylocked/what-are-abi-encoding-functions-in-solidity-0-4-24-c1a90b5ddce8)), but not changed `keccak256(a, b, c)` into `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b, c))`, done in v0.5.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.26;

contract Test {
    
    function pre_v0_5_keccak256encodingFormatStandard() external returns (bool, bool) {
        return (
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(uint8(4))) == keccak256(uint8(4)),
            keccak256(abi.encode(uint8(4))) == keccak256(uint8(4))
            );
    }    
}
```